# adding rank of size column in r

Tags: r

I have these set of variables in the column Num I want to create another column that ranks them with size similar to rankt below but I don't like how this is done.

```
 x <- data.frame("Num" = c(2,5,2,7,7,7,2,5,5))

x$rankt <- rank(x$Num)

  Num rankt
1   2     2
2   5     5
3   2     2
4   7     8
5   7     8
6   7     8
7   2     2
8   5     5
9   5     5
```

Desired Outcome I would like for rankt

```
  Num rankt
1   2     1
2   5     2
3   2     1
4   7     3
5   7     3
6   7     3
7   2     1
8   5     2
9   5     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, a crude approach is to turn them to factors, which are just increasing numbers with labels, and then fetch those numbers:

```r
x <- data.frame("Num" = c(2,5,2,7,7,7,2,5,5))
x$rankt <- as.numeric(as.factor( rank(x$Num) ))
x
```

It produces:

```
  Num rankt
1   2     1
2   5     2
3   2     1
4   7     3
5   7     3
6   7     3
7   2     1
8   5     2
9   5     2
```

Comment: is it enough to do `as.numeric(as.factor(x$Num))`

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x1 <- x %>% 
  mutate(rankt=dense_rank(desc(-Num)))
```

[image]